# Dynamic Radio Button Group in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, radio-button

The user will input their Id number then the accounts tied to this Id number will be presented(radio buttons) . They could have 1 or even 10 accounts returned(radio buttons). I need to have them
update their account to a Y, N. The account Id is what makes up the radio groups. Now I need to know who to loop through these radio buttons to see what they selected.

```
<cfif isDefined('FORM.bnt2')>
    <cfloop index="i" list="#form.fieldnames#">
        <cfquery  name="accept" datasource="#request.dsn#">
            UPDATE opt SET 
            f14 = '#evaluate(i)#'
            WHERE f4 = '#FORM.id#'
        </cfquery>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>                                                              

<cfform  name="frm2" id="form2" method="post" action="">
    <cfinput type="radio" name="#f5#" value="y"> 
    <cfinput type="radio" name="#f5#" value="n">
    <cfinput type="hidden" name="id" value="#f4#" />
    <cfinput name="bnt2" type="image" class="btn" src="images/accept.gif" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: Form name? or field name?  If you dump the Form scope, you should be able to see all the things in there, then u can loop through the struct or the list of fieldnames to do whatever you need.

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to do...
<cfif isDefined('FORM.bnt2')>
<cfloop index="i" list="#form.fieldnames#">
<cfquery  name="accept" datasource="#request.dsn#">
UPDATE opt SET 
f14 = '#evaluate(i)#'
WHERE f4 = '#FORM.ssn#'
</cfquery>
</cfloop>
</cfif>                                                              <cfform  name="frm2" id="form2" method="post" action="">
<cfinput type="radio" name="#f5#" value="y"> 
<cfinput type="radio" name="#f5#" value="n">
<cfinput type="hidden" name="id" value="#f4#" />
<cfinput name="bnt2" type="image" class="btn" src="images/accept.gif" value="Submit"/>

Comment: For the love of all that is holy .. please do not use #form.SSN# ;) There are plenty of tools available for creating unique identifiers suitable for use in general/insecure forms.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** use evaluate!

**Do** use cfqueryparam!

And fix those variables names, `f5`, `btn2` etc are not good names.

Anyway, I'm not entirely certain what you're doing, but here's a code snippet for you:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop index="CurField" list="#Form.FieldNames#">
    <br/>#CurField#=#XmlFormat(Form[CurField])#
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

That should give you what you need to make things work.

Note the `XmlFormat` is for display - generally not done in queries (storing data in the database), but instead when it is displayed to a browser. (Can also use `HtmlEditFormat` if you prefer.)

Comment: I need to get the value of the radio button, if the user selected Y or N. The Field names are going to be dynamically generated from id's in the database to form Radio Groups. When I try to <cfloop index="CurField" list="#form.fieldnames#"> to find the value of the radio button I will only get the value from the submit button.

Comment: If neither option is clicked, nothing will be in the form struct.  Only if one of the options is selected will it show up.

Comment: The options are selected, I just don't know the name of the radio field to update the database because the name of the field will be different each time (<cfinput type="radio" name="#f5#" value="n">).

Comment: In addition to what jarofclay says, if one of the values must be provided, set the default option to have a `selected` attribute.

Comment: Also, instead of looping through, can you not just do this:
`<input type="hidden" name="TheCheckboxIsCalled" value="#f5#"/>` ?

Comment: The options need to be optional.

Comment: Ok, please update the question to give full details of what you're trying to do and why you're trying to do it.

Comment: I have updated my original question with some more background, does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, here was my final solution.

```
<cfif isDefined("FORM.bnt2")>
<cfloop index="id" list="#form.listofids#" delimiters=",">
<cfquery  name="accept" datasource="#request.dsn#">
UPDATE opt SET
F14 = '#Evaluate("form.select_#id#")#'
WHERE f5 = '#id#'
</cfquery>
</cfloop>
</cfif>


<cfform  name="frm2" id="form2" method="post" action="">
<cfoutput query="accountCheck" >
<cfinput type="radio" name="select_#f5#" value="y" required="yes" validateat="onsubmit" message="A value of Yes or No is required.">
<cfinput type="radio" name="select_#f5#" value="n" required="yes" validateat="onsubmit" message="A value of Yes or No is required.">
<cfinput type="hidden" name="listofids" value="#ValueList(accountCheck.f5)#" >
</cfoutput>
<cfinput name="bnt2" type="image" class="btn" src="images/accept.gif" value="x"  style="float:right;" />
</cfform>
```

Comment: Take another look at Peter Boughton's suggestions. There are several improvements you could make. Especially the note about cfqueryparam. BTW: Are you really storing SSN in a hidden field ..?